# My page doesnt show rss stored in database with new users created from db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, rss

I'm here because I'm having some troubles with a web page. My web page shows on it google news RSS. I take the XML code (link) with a RSS_PARSER library (PHP) and take its content to my database. On this db it's stored title, description, date and time, and a MD5 title (I don't really know what is this for) dynamically. This content stored on the db, must be shown on this web page, but here's the problem: There have been 2 users created since the beginning of the project. When you log in with this 2 users, this page shows RSS stored on the db, but when I create new users from the db, it doesn't show anything, db doesn't create these registries automatically. This is really weird because older users are the same way created than the newest ones. This project was created by other people, and I have no contact with them. That's why I'm really lost and  I don't understand why this is not working properly, no one changed the code. It should work fine! Any ideas?

This is my library: (This all was made with CodeIgniter)

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
 * This class is written based entirely on the work found below
 * www.techbytes.co.in/blogs/2006/01/15/consuming-rss-with-php-the-simple-way/
 * All credit should be given to the original author
 *
 * Example:

$this->load->library('rssparser');
$this->rssparser->set_feed_url('http://example.com/feed');
$this->rssparser->set_cache_life(30);
$rss = $this->rssparser->getFeed(6);  // Get six items from the feed

// Using a callback function to parse addictional XML fields

$this->load->library('rssparser', array($this, 'parseFile')); // parseFile method of current class

function parseFile($data, $item)
{
    $data['summary'] = (string)$item->summary;
    return $data;
}
*/


class RSSParser {

public $feed_uri            = NULL;                     // Feed URI
public $data                = FALSE;                    // Associative array containing all the feed items
public $channel_data        = array();                  // Store RSS Channel Data in an array
public $feed_unavailable    = NULL;                     // Boolean variable which indicates whether an RSS feed was unavailable
public $cache_life          = 0;                        // Cache lifetime
public $cache_dir           = './application/cache/';   // Cache directory
public $write_cache_flag    = FALSE;                    // Flag to write to cache
public $callback            = FALSE;                    // Callback to read custom data


function __construct($callback = FALSE)
{
    if ($callback)
    {
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

function parse()
{
    // Are we caching?
    if ($this->cache_life != 0)
    {
        $filename = $this->cache_dir.'rss_Parse_'.md5($this->feed_uri);

        // Is there a cache file ?
        if (file_exists($filename))
        {
            // Has it expired?
            $timedif = (time() - filemtime($filename));

            if ($timedif < ( $this->cache_life * 60))
            {
                $rawFeed = file_get_contents($filename);
            }
            else
            {
                // So raise the falg
                $this->write_cache_flag = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Raise the flag to write the cache
            $this->write_cache_flag = true;
        }
    }

    // Reset
    $this->data = array();
    $this->channel_data = array();

    // Parse the document
    if (!isset($rawFeed))
    {
        $rawFeed = file_get_contents($this->feed_uri);
    }

    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($rawFeed);

    if ($xml->channel)
    {
        // Assign the channel data
        $this->channel_data['title'] = $xml->channel->title;
        $this->channel_data['description'] = $xml->channel->description;

        // Build the item array
        foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
        {
            $data = array();
            $data['title'] = (string)$item->title;
            $data['description'] = (string)$item->description;
            $data['pubDate'] = (string)$item->pubDate;
            $data['link'] = (string)$item->link;
            $dc = $item->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
            $data['author'] = (string)$dc->creator;

            if ($this->callback)
            {
                $data = call_user_func($this->callback, $data, $item);
            }

            $this->data[] = $data;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Assign the channel data
        $this->channel_data['title'] = $xml->title;
        $this->channel_data['description'] = $xml->subtitle;

        // Build the item array
        foreach ($xml->entry as $item)
        {
            $data = array();
            $data['id'] = (string)$item->id;
            $data['title'] = (string)$item->title;
            $data['description'] = (string)$item->content;
            $data['pubDate'] = (string)$item->published;
            $data['link'] = (string)$item->link['href'];
            $dc = $item->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
            $data['author'] = (string)$dc->creator;

            if ($this->callback)
            {
                $data = call_user_func($this->callback, $data, $item);
            }

            $this->data[] = $data;
        }
    }

    // Do we need to write the cache file?
    if ($this->write_cache_flag)
    {
        if (!$fp = @fopen($filename, 'wb'))
        {
            echo "RSSParser error";
            log_message('error', "Unable to write cache file: ".$filename);
            return;
        }

        flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
        fwrite($fp, $rawFeed);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

function set_cache_life($period = NULL)
{
    $this->cache_life = $period;
    return $this;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

function set_feed_url($url = NULL)
{
    $this->feed_uri = $url;
    return $this;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/* Return the feeds one at a time: when there are no more feeds return false
 * @param No of items to return from the feed
 * @return Associative array of items
*/
function getFeed($num)
{
    $this->parse();

    $c = 0;
    $return = array();

    foreach ($this->data AS $item)
    {
        $return[] = $item;
        $c++;

        if ($c == $num)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/* Return channel data for the feed */
function & getChannelData()
{
    $flag = false;

    if (!empty($this->channel_data))
    {
        return $this->channel_data;
    }
    else
    {
        return $flag;
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/* Were we unable to retreive the feeds ?  */
function errorInResponse()
{
    return $this->feed_unavailable;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/* Initialize the feed data */ 
function clear()
{
    $this->feed_uri     = NULL;
    $this->data         = FALSE;
    $this->channel_data = array();
    $this->cache_life   = 0;
    $this->callback     = FALSE;

    return $this;
}
}
```